# Python My Random Numbers arent generating properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

Heres the code

```
diff = raw_input("Easy Medium or Hard: ")
if diff == "Easy"or"easy"or"E"or"e":
    x = random.randint(0,100)
    coefx = random.randint(0,100)
    y = random.randint(0,100)
    coefy = random.randint(0,100)
    z = random.randint(0,100)
    coefz = random.randint(0,100)
elif diff == "Medium"or"medium"or"M"or"m":
    x = random.randint(400,500)
    coefx = random.randint(0,500)
    y = random.randint(0,500)
    coefy = random.randint(0,500)
    z = random.randint(0,500)
    coefz = random.randint(0,500)
```

when i only run one part it functions properly but when i put both piece's of code together my random numbers are always within 0,100 please help

Answer (score 1):

```
if diff == "Easy" or "easy" or "E" or "e":
```

will always be true. You can only use "or" between true/false values, and non-empty strings are true. You can either switch to whole boolean expressions:

```
if diff == "Easy" or diff == "easy" or diff == "e" ...
```

or use a list:

```
if diff in ["Easy", "easy", "E", "e"]:
```